# given p>1, whats an example of f where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f| < \infty$ but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f|^p = \infty$

Tags: integration

given p>1, whats an example of  f where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f| < \infty$ but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f|^p = \infty$

what about vica-versa? that is whats an example of g where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g| = \infty$ but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g|^p < \infty$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The former is caused by functions that blow up too rapidly near a point.  Think about functions of the form $f(x) = x^{-a} 1_{[0,1]}$.

The latter is caused by functions that decay too slowly near $\infty$.  Think about functions of the form $f(x) = x^{-a} 1_{[1,\infty)}$.

Comment: ok for the first one i came up with x^(-1/p).

for the second one i have x^(-1).